# Drupal and Solr - bias based on custom fields

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I have Drupal 7 with Solr 3 integrated.

Looking at the biasing, I am wondering how I can bias off a field I have made called "Category". Items are in category 1, 2, or 3 and I would like to give some search result boosting to category 1, does anyone know how I could achieve this?

I see I can give bias based on whether something is sticky or promoted to home page so could possibly use those check boxes as substitutes but wonder if there's a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but it seems `Apache Solr Term Proximity` module has the provision to boost the terms. Let me know if this helps. 
http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_proximity

Otherwise you might need to do custom coding. You can go through the below article to get an idea about the same:
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/boosting-solr-search-results-query-time